# Delphi & Azure-Cognitive-Services example: always 401 Access denied

Tags: azure, delphi, text-to-speech

I am using CE 10.4 and this example from Stephen Ball:
https://github.com/DelphiABall/Azure-Cognitive-Services

From that example, I tried "Speech Service" and always get a 401:
*Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource.*

Fiddler shows, that subscription-key is sent in the Body, not Header.

My Key works in other Application.

As the Code is published from an official Embarcadero Representative, I assume, the Code is right.

Can anybody confirm this behavior - and/or knows, how to change the Code?

Ciao Luigi

Answer (score 0):

In the meantine, the issue is fixed.
Stephen updated the repository.